# Using ICACLS to only allowing Administrator to access a folder. All other users to be denied access

Tags: permissions, uac, icacls

I need only Administrators to be able to access a particular folder. None other than Administrator should be able to access that folder. This has to be achieved using icacls command.

I have used the following command after surfing the net but since I am novice at NTFS and UAC, I am not sure what is wrong with the command:

***icacls "c:\abc" /deny users:F***

However, this command seems to deny even the Administrator to access "abc" folder. Just to be sure(based on my very limited knowledge), I created a Standard user and ran the above command. Then I logged on to Admin account and tried accessing the folder but got denied.

I also tried running the following command to explicitly grant Admin permission but this failed too because the folder access is denied to all:

***icacls "C:\abc" /grant administrators:F***

Havent been able to figure out how to selective allow only administrator to access a folder while all other users to be denied access.

Comment: This question really needs to be moved to superuser. But basically: `icacls C:\abc /inheritance:r /grant Administrators:F`

Comment: Thank you Bill. This is exactly what I was looking for.